# Comparing blurriness of two similar images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-processing, image-stitching

I'm working on a prototype application to create a map (image) of a tissue scanned with a microscope. To do so, I am:

1. recording a video while I use the microscope to "explore" the tissue
2. extracting some frames
3. stitching them to obtain a panorama image.

The code to extract frames from the video is simple and self explaining:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('.\images\microscope2.avi')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  if (count / 20) * 20 == count:
      cv2.imwrite("./images/microscope/frame%d.jpg" % (count/20), image)
  if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
      break
  count += 1
```

As you can notice, I'm simply extracting one frame every 20. My current problem is that some frames are blurry, so the stitching algorithm can't detect the features in order to align and overlap the images.

One solution could be to take some - let's say 3 - consecutive frames every 20, find the one that is less blurry and discard the others.

Other ideas on how I could change my approach are welcome (as a comment), please keep in mind that I'm working on a prototype so I'd like to avoid spending too much time coding the solution. Also, it does not need to run in realtime.

**The question:**

Is there a smart/simple way to compare very similar images in order to tell which one is less (or more) blurry?

Comment: Regarding your "tissue exploring": You stop at a position, let's say for at least 3 frames, then move your slide (Are these your "blurry" images? Do we talk about motion blur?), and stop at the next position, again for at least 3 frames? If this holds (more or less), just calculate frame-wise differences. There should be "neighbouring" frames with minimal differences, when you stop at a fixed position (if frame rate is suitable high). These are your desired frames - and so you don't need a fixed step size while extracting.

Comment: @HansHirse yes motion blur in first place, but also (for some reason I don't understand) when I stop at a position as you described the image stays blurry for a second before it gets good focus... yet the microscope I use has no auto-focus. Good idea anyway, I'll try and see how it goes.

Comment: When you also have to deal with autofocus blur while staying at a fixed position, my idea might need some extension: You'll get similar "neighbouring" frames twice in a short while (first the similar blurry frames, then the similar focussed frames). Maybe, one can use that information and neglect the first "hit". Also, do you need an instantaneous decision on a given image (like "real-time" processing) - or can you extract the "indices" of the frames and later extract the frames themselves from the video? That would be a requirement for my idea.

Comment: No need for realtime (I'm adding the information to the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blurriness of an image can be estimated with

```
cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()
```

See also this excellent post https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/ from which this suggestion was taken.

Comment: I see this often, maybe due to Adrian's popularity. Does the Laplacian approach also/really work for autofocus related blurring in microscopy? Most examples I see deal with motion blur or autofocus blur of "natural scenes". Would be interested in sources regarding this topic.

Comment: As far as I have tested, it does not work as well as for natural scenes. The point is that - in my case - I'm looking at sparse cells so part of the image looks blurry even if the cells are in focus. I'm still trying to see if I can tune this to work, for example by substracting the average Laplacian to each image Laplacian (really blurry images should still give lower values so I expect to get negative values). UV: the answer is relevant, @stan deserves the right to add comments.

Comment: @HansHirse This article http://optica.csic.es/papers/icpr2k.pdf might be of interest. As far as I can tell the method above was originally proposed there.

Comment: It works: the difference of the measure is less than in natural scenes but I compared the "worst" and the "best" frames every 30 frames in my video. Worst frames are nearly always showing motion blur, best frames never are.